# How to create a sequelizejs service without creating a table

Tags: sequelize.js

I need a sequelizejs service where I can hook in a number of actions not related to any table and I therefore want to prevent the auto-generation of tables. How can I do this?

Comment: what have you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Bad question. I use feathers generate to make a service and selected Sequelize and in the nature of Sequelize it will make a table for me. I had to create my service selecting option 'A customer service', which generates a class where I can put all my logic.